# Converting a mixed fraction to a float number in Netezza

Tags: sql, netezza

I have a field with numbers stored as text in 3 formats:

```
xx. (example: 31.)
xx.x (example: 31.2)
xx x/x (example: 31 2/7)
```

For the final result, I need all numbers to be in decimal format (that is, xx.x).

Converting the first two formats into decimals is fairly simple, but I haven't quite figured out how to convert the last case, as a simple CAST function doesn't work. I've used the INSTR function to isolate all the fractional cases of these numbers, but I don't know where to go from there. I've looked at other examples but some of the functions referenced (like SUBSTRING_INDEX) don't exist in Netezza.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the help everyone. I forgot to close this out, I actually figured out a way to do it:

```
select
  case when instr(num,'/') > 0 then 
       cast(substr(num,1,2) as float) 
       + (cast(substr(num,4,1) as float)/cast(substr(num,6,1) as float))
  when instr(num,'.') > 0 then cast(substr(num,1,4) as float) 
  else cast(num as float)
end as float_num
```

Answer (score 3):

I think @Niederee has the solution from brute force, but I'd use the [sql extensions toolkit](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.2.0/com.ibm.nz.sqltk.doc/r_sqlext_regexp_extract.html?lang=en).

```
create temporary table fractions (
  val nvarchar(64)
) distribute on random;

insert into fractions values ('2.');
insert into fractions values ('2.3');
insert into fractions values ('31 2/7');
insert into fractions values('2 0/8');
insert into fractions values('516 56/537');

select
  val
  ,case
    when regexp_like(val,'^[\d\.]+$') then val::numeric(20,10) --Cast it if we can.
    when regexp_like(val,'^[\d\.\s\/]+$')
      then regexp_extract(val,'\d+',1,1)::numeric(20,10) --Whole.
        + ( 
          regexp_extract(val,'\d+',1,2)::numeric(20,10) --Numerator.
          / regexp_extract(val,'\d+',1,3)::numeric(20,10) --Denominator.
        )
    else null
  end
from
  fractions;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
create temp table so_test (
txt_val varchar(100)
);

insert into so_test values ('31.');
insert into so_test values ('31.2');
insert into so_test values ('31 2/7');

select txt_val
, cast(decode(substr(txt_val,1,instr(txt_val,' ')),'',txt_val,substr(txt_val,1,instr(txt_val,' ')))  as numeric(18,2))  as root
,cast(substr(txt_val,instr(txt_val,' ')+1,length(txt_val)-instr(txt_val,'/')) as numeric(18,2))
/cast(substr(txt_val,instr(txt_val,'/')+1,length(txt_val)) as numeric(18,2)) as fraction
,cast(root + case when fraction = 1 then 0 else fraction end as numeric(3,1)) as num_val

from so_test
```